# Using position fixed with content that uses absolute and float:left

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I'm using a sidebar menu that uses position fixed and slides out from left to right using JavaScript. This works ok apart from one page that is being troublesome for me. The troublesome page contains the fixed side bar and content to the right that contains absolute positon and floating elements that are suppose fill the screen apart from the sidebar area. The boxes should be 50% wide of the free area space. Currently the method I'm using results in uneven boxes and I've tried several methods to overcome this problem with no luck.

I believe the problem is an result because of the `left:100px` previously used on the parent div element.I've included a JsFiddle of the problem to make this a lot easier for the community to help me.

Below is the HTML code:

```
<div class="menuWrapper">
    <div class="menubarTrigger">
        <span>Menu Bar</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contentWrapper">
    <div class="servicesWrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">SEO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Site Maintence</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Consultancy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Misc</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Below is the CSS code:

```
body, html{margin:0;}
.menuWrapper{background-color:#000;height:100%;position:fixed;z-index:100;}
.menubarTrigger{background-color:#1c1c1c;cursor:pointer;float:right;height:100%;width:100px;color:white;}
.menubarTrigger span{position:absolute;top:50%;left:18%;}
.contentWrapper{height:100%;left:100px;position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;}
.servicesWrapper{height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;}
.servicesWrapper ul{height:100%;left:0;margin:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;z-index:10;padding:0;}
.servicesWrapper ul li{background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #bbb;display:table;float:left;height:50%;text-align:center;width:50%;}
.servicesWrapper ul li a{color:#fff;display:table-cell;font-size:40px;letter-spacing:3px;position:relative;transform:translateY(50px);;vertical-align:middle;}
.servicesWrapper ul li:nth-child(1){background-color:#ccc;}
.servicesWrapper ul li:nth-child(2){background-color:#ddd;}
.servicesWrapper ul li:nth-child(3){background-color:#eee;}
```

And you can find the [Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bybe/qn461rmd/17/) and may need to look closely to see that the right hand side boxes are not the same width as those on the left.

Comment: phari was faster. If you menu has a fixed width (100px) the container needs to be 100% - 100px width. add "width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px)" also for a bit more browser conpatibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.contentWrapper{height:100%;left:100px;position:fixed;top:0;width:calc(100% - 100px);}
```

Note: In the `calc` expression, there must be spaces between the values and the minus sign - some browsers do not interpret the expression correctly otherwise.

Comment: That's fantastic and I'm annoyed with myself for not remembering `width:calc` :) Thanks so much!